# How to compile modules for ARM v7I in android?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, linux-kernel, arm

I am new in Linux world and have a short knowledge of compilers.. so anyone know how to compile tun.ko module for arm v7I? I am facing some problem.

```
<3>[16823.190948] tun: version magic '2.6.29 preempt mod_unload ARMv6 ' should be '2.6.38.6 preempt mod_unload ARMv7 '
```

I am using latest NDK but having same problem every time, I used other compiler too but still.

Comment: Kernel modules are not compiled with / related to the NDK. You need the kernel compiler toolchain thing but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Android NDK also contain compiler toolchain...i confuse between which compiler should i use to compile tun.ko module for my kernel,....

Comment: there are some details here: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Building_Kernel_from_source or here: http://hex.ro/wp/blog/compile-an-android-kernel-module-outside-the-kernel-source-tree/

Comment: @auselen, armv7l is short for ARM architecture generation 7 (i.e. ARM11**, Cortex-A5/A7/A8/A9) in little endian mode.

Comment: @KlaasvanGend What does that imply? Afaik cpu should be able to switch between big and little endian modes. Then I guess v7l should be used to indicate binary format of some object files, like elf, abi or kernel.

Comment: @KlaasvanGend, cpu should NOT switch byte addressing while running code, doing so can foobar the network code (and possible more) where byte addressing is required to be in a certain order so the kernel is compiled to be either Big endian or Little endian.

Answer (score 0):

you have many cross compiler tool-chain like the one i am using is  gcc-4.3.3,Multi-lib,gnueabi to compile using this you need to set ARCH = arm and PATH = "path to cross compiler"  and CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-